# Nginx/OwnCloud requests being sent to wrong directory

Tags: php, nginx, owncloud

I have a server running Nginx with an instance of OwnCloud. The root of the webserver is at `/data/domain.com/www/` and the root of the OwnCloud files is `/data/domain.com/www/cloud/`.

The OwnCloud pages load perfectly fine, so I can browse and upload files. I have Z-Push working, but I cannot share files. When I go to share, the request is sent to the wrong directory as per the errors:

```
2016/06/01 20:47:31 [error] 7758#0: *117 "/data/domain.com/www/ocs-provider/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.1.1.1, server: domain.com, request: "GET /ocs-provider/ HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
2016/06/01 20:47:31 [error] 7758#0: *121 open() "/data/domain.com/www/ocs/v1.php/cloud/shares/36/unshare" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.1.1.1, server: domain.com, request: "GET /ocs/v1.php/cloud/shares/36/unshare?format=json HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
```

The folders, ocs and ocs-provider are both located in the cloud directory, which is inside of the www directory. Essentially, requests to those folders are being pointed at the directory above.

Interestingly, it lists the host as domain.com - but the OwnCloud instance is running from `cloud.domain.com`. My initial thoughts were that OwnCloud is pointing requests at the wrong domain, but in my config.php for OwnCloud I have the following:

```
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => 'cloud.domain.com',
    1 => 'domain.com',
  ),
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'https://cloud.domain.com/',
```

For my cloud.domain.com vhosts config I have the following:

```
server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

        server_name cloud.domain.com;
        return 302 https://$host$request_uri;

        error_log /var/log/nginx_error.log error;
        access_log /var/log/nginx_access.log;

}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name cloud.domain.com;
   #####ssl block


    client_max_body_size 10G;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    gzip off;


    root /data/domain.com/www/cloud/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;


    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx_error.log error;
    access_log /var/log/nginx_access.log;

    location ~ ^/(?:\.htaccess|data|config|db_structure\.xml|README){
            deny all;
    }

    rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;

    index index.php;

    location / {
            # The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger
            rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
            rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

            rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
            rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

            rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
            fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }


    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=7200";
        # Add headers to serve security related headers
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
        # Optional: Don't log access to assets
        access_log off;
    }

  # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|swf)$ {
        access_log off;
  }
```

}

Any ideas as to why my requests are going to the wrong place and what I can do to rectify? I'm running out of ideas! :(

Comment: Could you try `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` instead of 302. Config looks pretty good. I'm running it in the same way and it works for me.